# How can I write conditional regex replace in PySpark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, regexp-replace

I'm trying to get an if else statement working in the form of `when()` and `otherwise()` function. I tried thinking of many ways but my problem is the `when()` statement needs a column. Is there a way to get the following code working in `when()` and `otherwise()` format?

```
get_data = spark.sql("SELECT STRING({}) AS {} FROM {} WHERE Mobile='{}'".format(dynamic_tag_mapping_column_name, match[0], dynamic_tag_mapping_table_name, mobile_numbers[mob])).collect()[0][0]
if get_data!='0':
     textList.append(campaign_segment_text.withColumn('CampaignSMSText', func.expr("regexp_replace(CampaignSMSText, '{}', {})".format(match[0], get_data)))
else:
     textList.append(campaign_segment_text.withColumn('CampaignSMSText', func.expr("regexp_replace(CampaignSMSText, '{}', {})".format(match[0], dynamic_default_value)))
```

What I'm trying to achieve is if I get the `get_data>0` value from database it will take the `get_data` value but if `get_data=0`, it will assign a default value that is set. I tried setting the String value to Int that I'm getting from the DB but that won't compare because `get_data` isn't a column. Is there anyway to get this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting `case when` inside `F.expr`?

```
get_data = spark.sql("SELECT {} AS {} FROM {} WHERE Mobile='{}'".format(dynamic_tag_mapping_column_name, match[0], dynamic_tag_mapping_table_name, mobile_numbers[mob])).collect()[0][0]

textList.append(
    campaign_segment_text.withColumn(
        'CampaignSMSText',
        func.expr(
            "regexp_replace(CampaignSMSText, '{}', case when {} != 0 then {} else {} end)".format(
                match[0], get_data, get_data, dynamic_default_value
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: @VarunNagrare I found a missing close bracket in your code (and also my code), could you please try again?

Comment: Okay I'll check it

Comment: Yeah it worked! Thanks man. Your answer helped me a second time. :D

Comment: I know UDF's are slow. I just wanted to practice since I don't know how UDF's work.

Comment: yes you can use udf. the udf will take a string, pattern, and pattern to replace as input arguments, and return a replaced string

Comment: I read somewhere that we can convert a Python function to Spark UDF. What steps would that need?

Comment: see https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.udf